# Include same script with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have created a widget, which customer will embed in their sites. 
That widget content different parts which can be included separately anywhere in customers site.
I have written on script to get the information from back end. But for that i have to pass different parameters.

So how can i pass the parameters to script so i can differentiate if same script included multiple times in same page.

e.g

```
    Widget 1
    <div>
        <span>...</span>
    </div>
    <script src="/xyz.js" key="8ea1878312fa3e199822366864b4a6fc" value="7"></script>

Or 
<script src="/xyz.js?value=7&key=8ea1878312fa3e199822366864b4a6fc"></script>


    Widget 2
    <div>
        <span>...</span>
    </div>
    <script src="/xyz.js" key="8ea1878312fa3e199822366864b4a6fc" value="10"></script>

Or 
<script src="/xyz.js?value=10&key=8ea1878312fa3e199822366864b4a6fc"></script>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You could include a `data-` attribute in a `<div>` tag and then have the JS read it that way.

Comment: Do you need to track if the script has been included or not? You could add some sort of a paramter to your /xyz.js?ref=SOME_UNIQUE_REF and track that parameter on your backend or you could run some code in your xyz.js that informs your server about it being loaded.

Comment: @ned, How can i get the parameters in script? I have already searched on the solution you gave but i found they have used id attribute to get the data-attributes. Its possible if i added js once but what if i added js multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery, you can declare an object, who contains all functions, which use your script. Then declare `init()` function in your script. In this function should be all actions, which generates your widgets on the page.

Here is Example (using **Laravel**):

your-script.js:

```
var myModule = {};

myModule.someAction = function (data, event) {
    var parameter = $(this).data('parameter');
    // code here
};

myModule.someAnotherAction = function (data, event) {
    // code here
};

myModule.init = function () {
    $('[data-mywidget]')on('click', myModule.someAction);
};
```

index.html:

```
<!-- Your script -->
    <script src="{{ asset('your-script.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Some markup here -->

<div data-mywidget data-parameter="{{ $my_dynamic_attribute }}">
<span>...</span>
</div>

<!-- Some markup here -->

<!-- Main script -->
<script>       
$(document).ready(function() {
    myModule.init();
});
</script
```

Comment: What if I want to include same code twice on same page?

Comment: What target of this?

Comment: Actually i have created a widget which will be embed in multiple site. There is a common JS for each widget. So need to pass the dynamic parameters depends on what i will perform the backend functionality

Comment: In my example you can use dara-attributes to pass the dynamic parameters